# Do Lagrange multipliers find all extrema?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

Given $f(x,y) = x^2+y^2$ and the constraint $x^4+y^4=16$, find the maximum and minimum values. Using lagrange multipliers, I found the relationship y=±x and the critical points $(8^.25, 8^.25), (8^.25, -8^.25), (-8^.25, 8^.25), (-8^.25, -8^.25) = 2\sqrt{8}$. However, there must be another set of critical points and this is especially noticeable when graphed.

Am I not seeing another relationship between $f$ and the constraint? I read online that now all extrema can be found my lagrange multipliers, so is that the case?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, if you use the method correctly and do not make logic/algebra errors. You lost four solutions. Please show your work and pay careful attention.

Comment: Odds are that you lost some solutions by dividing an equation by a quantity that was equal to $0$ at those solutions. Go back and check every place where you cancelled a factor from both sides of an equation.